# Iterating through web pages by modifying URL with for loop

Tags: python, html, url, web-scraping, iteration

I'm trying to scrape the data from tripadvisor for a specific hotel.

the URL for the hotel in tripadvisor is

https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g39143-d92240-Reviews-Hawthorn_Suites_by_Wyndham_Wichita_East-Wichita_Kansas.html

with the page delimiter occuring after "d92240-Reviews" with the key "-or5-" in multiples of 5 as the page returns 5 reviews.

eg

https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g39143-d92240-Reviews-or5-Hawthorn_Suites_by_Wyndham_Wichita_East-Wichita_Kansas.html

https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g39143-d92240-Reviews-or10-Hawthorn_Suites_by_Wyndham_Wichita_East-Wichita_Kansas.html

with pages that with URLs ending in "&start=(number of results)" I can create a for loop to return each page

```
for i in range(0,200,5):
  url = http://blahblahblah&start= + str(i)
```

However I don't know how to do that with my tripadvisor url.

Answer (score 1):

Here you go :

```
initial='https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g39143-d92240-Reviews-Hawthorn_Suites_by_Wyndham_Wichita_East-Wichita_Kansas.html'
url_part1='https://www.tripadvisor.com/Hotel_Review-g39143-d92240-Reviews-or'
url_part2='-Hawthorn_Suites_by_Wyndham_Wichita_East-Wichita_Kansas.html'
print (initial)
for index in range (5,200, 5):
    print(url_part1+str(index)+url_part2)
```